# Joomla call internal controller function

Tags: php, joomla, controller, components

How can I call a other method / function in the same controller file?

For example: controller.php

```
class MyController extends JControllerLegacy
{
   function test() {
       $var = otherfunction();
       echo $var;
   }
   function othermethod() {
       return 'something';
   }
}
```

I get an Error in browser. 
Fatal error: "**Call to undefined function othermethod()**".

I would be glad to get help... Sorry for my bad english (;

Answer (score 1):

In order to call method in the same class you can use `this`.And to call function you need to include file that has definition of the function.

```
class MyController extends JControllerLegacy
{
   function test() {
       //include_once file_has_otherfunction_definition.php
       //$var = otherfunction();
       $var = $this->othermethod();
       echo $var;
   }
   function othermethod() {
       return 'something';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in flat php programming you can call function just by function name like:

```
otherfunction();
```

but if proramming Object-oriented (like code that you insert), you must use **$this->functionName/** to call other function. So test() function must become like this:

```
function test() {
   $var = **$this->otherfunction();**
   echo $var;
```

}
for more information about Object-Oriented PHP see [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/)

Comment: Thank you very much mohsenkw... good site, qualified users, fast responses! i like :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling joomla controller properlly.

here is the syntax:
class component_nameControllerController_Name{
}

ex:class virtuemartControllercort extends Jcontroller{
}
here virtuemart is the component name and cort is the controller.Controller indicates the this is the controller.